# Add an ImageType inside a form: "cannot read index ... doesn't implement \ArrayAccess"?

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I  have a small issue with a custom Type in a field of a form : I am trying to add an "ImageType" related to an "Image" entity, which has "url" and "alt" as variables.
I get this error :

> Cannot read index "url" from object of type
>   "Proxies__CG__\OC\PlatformBundle\Entity\Image" because it doesn't
>   implement \ArrayAccess.

Here is the Type:

```
<?php
// src/OC/PlatformBundle/Form/ImageType.php

namespace OC\PlatformBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;

class ImageType extends AbstractType
{
  public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
  {
    $builder
      ->add('url', TextType::class)
      ->add('alt', TextType::class)
    ;
  }

  public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
  {
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
      'data_class' => 'OC\PlatformBundle\Entity\Image'
    ));
  }

  public function getName()
  {
    return 'oc_platformbundle_image';
  }
}
```

The form:

```
class AdvertType extends AbstractType
{
  public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
  {
    $builder
      ->add('title', TextType::class)
      ->add('date', DateType::class)
      ->add('categories', EntityType::class, array(
            'class'    => 'OCPlatformBundle:Category',
            'choice_label' => 'name',
            'multiple' => true
          ))
      ->add('image', ImageType::class)
      ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Create Task'))    ;
  }
```

And the entity :

```
<?php

namespace OC\PlatformBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Image
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="image")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="OC\PlatformBundle\Repository\ImageRepository")
 */
class Image
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="url", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $url;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="alt", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $alt;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set url
     *
     * @param string $url
     *
     * @return Image
     */
    public function setUrl($url)
    {
        $this->url = $url;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get url
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getUrl()
    {
        return $this->url;
    }

    /**
     * Set alt
     *
     * @param string $alt
     *
     * @return Image
     */
    public function setAlt($alt)
    {
        $this->alt = $alt;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get alt
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAlt()
    {
        return $this->alt;
    }
}
```

I don't have any Array in the Image class, so I am not sure what throws the issue.

Comment: You might need to implement the `getParent()` function to signify that you want this to extend the `EntityType` class (Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType)

Comment: @JasonRoman Thanks, I edited my post, I added `getParent()` but it throws an error.

Comment: Thinking about it more, you wouldn't want it to be EntityType because you have a new form with multiple fields, and EntityType would just be a single choice that you are selecting.  Did you create a Twig template for your new field?

Comment: I think I've spotted the error - `setDefaultOptions()` was deprecated and removed in 3.0, you need to use `public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)` instead, and fix your `use` statement from the interface to the actual class.  If that works I'll post an answer with more details.

Comment: That error is raised on `PropertyAccessor::read Index()` method, which is heavily used by Form component.  `"Proxies__CG__\XYZ"` are proxy files classes auto generated by cache system (often on prod environment). It sounds you've an old cache file. Try clear dev and prod cache (`rm -r ...`)

Comment: @JasonRoman thanks, no it wasn't that, although it is good to know. But in another form, the previous method with `setDefaultOptions()` worked fine, even though I am on the new version of Symfony. The error is still the same `option class is missing`.

Comment: @felipsmartins thanks, I tried `php bin/console cache:clear`, or `rm -r var/cache/*` (not sure about the path, I only have the "dev" folder inside), and it does not solve the issue.

Comment: If you're on Symfony 3.0 then `setDefaultOptions()` won't actually do anything - you may think it works but it's just going to be an empty function that will never be called.  Remove the `getParent()` function altogether (I was wrong on that), then change to `configureOptions()` as in my previous comment and try that.

Comment: @JasonRoman correct, I forgot to remove `getParent()`, it works fine now, thanks! You can add an answer if you want, I will accept it.

Comment: Okay, also you can edit your post to remove the part about the `EntityType`.  I notice that a lot of your posts are referencing code that was valid in Symfony 2.x but no longer in 3.0.  When you are reading the documentation make sure you have selected the current (3.0) branch.  The [Symfony blog](http://symfony.com/blog/) also has a lot of good posts titled 'New in Symfony x.x' that discuss new features and deprecations.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You are receiving this error because Symfony is looking for the data class of your form type but cannot find it.  Your code would have worked for Symfony 2.x versions, where `setDefaultOptions()` was valid.  Beginning with Symfony 2.7, that method was [deprecated in favor of `configureOptions()`](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-7-form-and-validator-updates#deprecated-setdefaultoptions-in-favor-of-configureoptions) and removed entirely in 3.0.

So, your function exists in your form class but it will never be referenced by Symfony.  Your debug toolbar may not even show this deprecation since it was removed entirely in 3.0.  Simpler form types may not error if you make this same mistake, but `setDefaultOptions()` will never be called in either case, so I would go through and check your other forms to make sure they are valid as well.

As a solution, change this:

```
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class AdvertType extends AbstractType
{
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'OC\PlatformBundle\Entity\Image',
        ));
    }
}
```

to this:

```
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class AdvertType extends AbstractType
{
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'OC\PlatformBundle\Entity\Image',
        ));
    }
}
```

Comment: It also works like a charm if you change data_class to Image::class

Comment: True, and with newer version of Symfony that should be the preferred method